# How can I change my Default Selected Text color in utils.MultiSelectSpinner

Tags: colors, spinner, selected

Ref Image:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
 <com.so.utils.MultiSelectSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_upload_wallcat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:popupBackground="@color/bg"/>
```

Main Activity:

```
spinner_cat.setListener(new MultiSelectSpinner.OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices) {
            if (indices.size() > 0) {
                cat_id = arrayList_catid.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++) {
                    cat_id = cat_id + "," + arrayList_catid.get(i);
                }
            } else {
                cat_id = "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void selectedStrings(List<String> strings) {

        }
    });
```

How can I change my default text color after selected? I tried so many times but every time I failed.

Comment: add image as ref

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpthP.jpg